In which instances are Clebsch Gordan coef. (CGC) used?
Let's consider an electron in the potential of an isotropic harmonic oscillator. Neglecting the spin, the Hamiltonian operator is given by
$$H = \frac{\mathbf{p}^2}{2m} + \frac{1}{2} m \omega^2 \mathbf{r}^2.
$$
Such a system can be described as the product of three harmonic oscillators with the same frequency. The ladder operators are denoted by $a_x$,$a_y$ and $a_z$. The transition to spherical coordinates can be done via operators:
$a_\theta = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(a_x + ia_y), \quad a_\phi = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(a_x - ia_y)$ and $a_z=a_z$
as well as the corresponding operators
$N_\theta = a_\theta^\dagger a_\theta, \quad N_\phi = a_\phi^\dagger a_\phi, \quad N_z = a_z^\dagger a_z.
$
I have a question. In this example, at some point we find an expression for the joint eigenstates of H and $L_z$. Those eigenstates are of the form $|n_\theta,n_\phi,n_z\rangle$. Then we find joint eigenvectors of $\vec  L^2$ and $L_z$ from those of $H$ and $L_z$. The way we find them, in the example, is by utilizing Clebsch-Gordan coef. and the algorithm/procedure for finding all the eigenstates. But I have a question, because this moment, in the example, confuses me:
Are CGC used exclusively in the case when we switch from the basis of eigenstates of the total angular momentum of a system/ tensor basis to that of the idividual angular momenta present in the system/ uncoupled tensor basis? Or it can be used in other scenarios as well?
Here we are switching between two different representations of the same basis $|n_{\phi},n_{\theta},n_z\rangle$ and $|n_x,n_y,n_z\rangle$ and not between basis that involve different angular momenta
Am I missing something here?
I don't see multiple angular momenta characterizing our system so that we can jump from an uncoupled basis to a coupled one

What example? What Clebsch Gordan coefficients? Are you making sense?

The example was the  electron in the potential of an isotropic harmonic oscillator.
The Clebsch Gordon coef. were used to find joint eigenstates of $L^2$ and $L_z$ from known joint eigenstates of H and $L_z$, whose expression is not of importance to me or to what I am after.

You don't need Clebsch-Gordan coefficients for a spin-0 charged particle in a Coulomb potential. You can simultaneously diagonalize $H$, $L^2$, and $L_z$, which is why the eigenstates are normally labeled $|n \ell m\rangle$ -- here $n$ is related to the eigenvalue of $H$, $\ell$ of $L^2$, and $m$ of $L_z$. Where you need Clebsch-Gordan coefficients is in addition of angular momenta. If you have two different angular momenta, such as two spins or one spin and one orbital angular momentum, you will need CG coefficients to translate between bases for describing that kind of system.

@Andrew Yes I agree. But still in our lecture, we considered the CGC and we switched from $|n_\theta,n_\phi,n_z\rangle$ $\rightarrow$ $|n,l,m\rangle$

So the reader is left to shadow-box with a lecture and a text unavailable to them? You are familiar with the central potential problem in spherical coordinates?

Oh I see, I misunderstood what you're saying. It might help to an equation or two to explain how you are using the Clebsch-Gordan coefficients, for context. (Something like $|n \ell m \rangle = f(C, |n_\theta, n_\phi, n_z\rangle)$, where $f$ is some function and $C$ are the CG coefficients). I think the zeroth order answer to your question is that at a deep level the CG coefficients are used to convert between different representations of angular momentum, but that abstract process can arise in unexpected situations, like CMB analysis (random example, Eq 6 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.00705).

In other words, the CG coefficients are a mathematical object that appears in the representation theory of the three dimensional rotation group $SO(3)$ or its double cover $SU(2)$. The physical interpretation of why we use them depends on the application.

You are discussing the 3d isotropic SHO in highly off-mainstream (sadistic) language, well-covered in A Messiah's QM, vI, Ch XII §15. The CGCs are a red herring, rising to a bluff!

Indeed, you are surveying the symmetric representations of SU(3), so you may imagine you are working out the horizontal Young Tableaux of that group, but, surely this is a notional red herring!
